# Unexplained space before title after TOC

Tags: spacing, titles

I have a main title page in my document, which is followed by a table of contents, then an actual title (without author or date and their respective predefined spacings) and yet I still end up with slightly more space at the top of the page than I want. Does anyone know why? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\predate{}
\postdate{}

\title{Title 2}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{1cm}

       \LARGE{\textbf{Main title}}

       \vspace{0.5cm}
        \Large
        Research thing
            
       \vspace{1.5cm}

       \textbf{Author}

       \vfill
            
       \LARGE{Research exploring research}
            
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\break 
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title 2 significance}

\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: size commands like `\LARGE` does not take arguments

Comment: @Matt add `showframe` as an option when loading `geometry`. I see no undue vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc ot titling p.4. With \setlength{\droptitle}{} in the preambule, it's perhaps ok for you. I tried with \setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}

Comment: -4.5em worked better for me, but this fixed it!